# Alternative to vuurmuur ( ncurses gui for iptables)

Tags: iptables

I am looking for an updated 64-bit alternative to vuurmuur, at the moment our firewall is a 32 bit machine, but vuurmuur uses 32-bit.

We can compile it ourselves or use 32-bit libs, but that seems to be quite inneficient. Writing iptables is not really an option either.

So does anyone know any good alternatives to vuurmuur that can be run through ncurses or something similar ?  (no webinterfaces)

Comment: have you considered just... learning the iptables syntax.

Comment: yea, thing is I can, problem is my other admins want a very fast and easy firewall setup. When we used vuurmuur we had about 540 lines generated in iptables. You can imagine that it is not the easiest to maintain. They want an easy way to use the firewall, routing and dpi.

Comment: Sorry, but why 'compiling it yourselves' is 'quite inefficient'?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but perhaps others are still looking for an answer to this question.

The following are not ncurses based but do not require a web interface. Both are actively developed (github based) projects and greatly simplify iptables yet still allow complex/advanced firewall configurations:

- [arno-iptables-firewall](https://github.com/arno-iptables-firewall/aif/)
- [firehol](http://firehol.org)

Both are also available in the standard debian repos.